# Were their eyes opened simultaneously in Genesis 3:7?

Tags: genesis, creation, adam

Genesis 3:6, 7 NIV

> <sup>**6**</sup> When the woman saw that the fruit of the tree was good for food and pleasing to the eye, and also desirable for gaining wisdom, she took some and ate it. She also gave some to her husband, who was with her, and he ate it. <sup>**7**</sup> ***Then the eyes of both of them were opened***, and they realized they were naked; so they sewed fig leaves together and made coverings for themselves.

In the above narrative, it's clear that the woman ate first before he gave the husband. The narrative goes on to say their eyes were opened giving an impression that this was simultaneously after the husband had eaten.

Were their eyes opened simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Genesis 3:

> 6 When the woman **saw** that the fruit of the tree was good for food and pleasing to the eye, and also desirable for gaining wisdom, she **took** some and **ate** it. She also **gave** some to her husband, who [was] with her, and he **ate** it. 7 Then the eyes of both of them were **opened**, and they **realized** they [were] naked; so they **sewed** fig leaves together and made coverings for themselves.

All the verbs are in consecutive imperfect form.
The first Hebrew word that starts verse 7 is

were opened,
וַתִּפָּקַ֙חְנָה֙ (wat·tip·pā·qaḥ·nāh)
**Conjunctive waw** | Verb - Nifal - **Consecutive imperfect** - third person feminine plural
Strong's 6491: To open, to be observant

The waw prefix connects the eye-opening action with Adam's eating action. I read the whole sequence as fast-moving actions. Their eyes might not have been opened simultaneously, but the realization of the nakedness was more-or-less simultaneous.

Were their eyes opened simultaneously in Genesis 3:7?

If not, then there was not much time elapsed between them. Everything was happening fast.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Law of Vows in Numbers 30, a husband can annul his wife's hasty, rash, unthinking vow.  When Eve ate of the fruit she did so knowingly, but in a state of deception.  In other words, she knew what she was doing, but at the same time she didn't know what she was doing.  She had just made a "vow" of sorts, to allow her eyes to be opened, but Adam could have annulled her vow by refusing to eat, and reprimanding her for it.  If Adam had done so, neither of their eyes would have been opened.  But when Adam also ate, he confirmed that he was "okay" with Eve's vow, and at that very moment, both had their eyes opened.

Comment: You haven't provided a clear claim demonstrating how you concluded that Adam and Eve were subject to the Law as given to Israel in Numbers 30. This feels more like an opinion than a conclusion from the text of Genesis.

Answer (score 1):

The eyes of both Adam and Eve would have been opened (Gen 3:7) simultaneously only if they had sinned simultaneously.

But they did not - Eve sinned first (see 1 Tim 2:14) and so her eyes were opened and then Adam sinned; his eyes were opened shortly after Eve's eyes.

Therefore, they were NOT opened simultaneously.

Comment: @ Dottard,if their eyes had been opened on different occasions shouldn't Eve have felt some change  prior to giving Adam the fruit. In 1 Tim 2 it only speaks about who was deceived first not about the opening of eyes

Comment: @collenndhlovu - I suggest Eve probably did feel a change prior to giving fruit to Adam which is why she did it.

Answer (score -1):

I love these questions as I started to write about this as well and do research it further.

It says she ate and then gave it to her husband. This means she bit it and then swallowed it and saw that she did not drop and then she gave it to her husband. I don't know if anyone had a partner with them and they are holding a pizza or a cake. Then they take a bite and swallow than they take after finishing and then give to their partner. In the old days when the kings wanted to make sure that they are not getting poison. They allowed the person to eat of it first and then see if anything happens and then if nothing happens the king would eat.

Well Eve was told that if she eats of this tree she would die. She was also under the impression also if she touches the tree as well. So She took of it and nothing happen. Then she bit it and nothing happened then she chewed it then nothing happened, then she swallowed it and it went down her throat and nothing happened. Then she turned to her husband and said here let us edit or mute any sound off here. but she gave it to her husband. Then he took it in his hands and nothing happened he bit of it as she bit of it and nothing happened to keep in mind the fruit is still in eve and she still isn't dead. Then he chews it and nothing happens then he swallows it and nothing happens.

Then it says both their eyes are open together. So realistically the timing it takes to eat and swallow this fruit would not have lead both their eyes to be open at the same time when one ate of the fruit first. It would lead the eyes of the first one to be open first and then the second would be open afterwards since that person opened their mouth and chewed later.

So the fact that the bible says both of their eyes were opened just means it isn't just one now but both of them. You can also do this scientifically take a lemon and now the test is in the day you eat of the lemon you will have the knowledge of sour and bitter and you will forever know what it taste like. Then take a bite of it chew it and swallow it and then go and give it to the next person. Then ask yourself who tasted it first and had the consequences first. Then let the second person do the same thing and then see what happens. Now both of their eyes are open to the sourness of a lemon. But who knew of the taste first.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer needs some  supporting references or Bible verses to support the assertions.